# Rearrange hierarchy in a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, hierarchy

I wonder if there exists a simple way to do the following thing in `R`:

Suppose I have a bunch of data on four cars: white BMW, black BMW, white GMC and black GMC. 
I put them in a list of lists named `cars`:

data on white BMW is in `cars[[1]][[1]]`, 
data on black BMW is in `cars[[1]][[2]]`, 
data on white GMC is in `cars[[2]][[1]]`, 
data on black GMC is in `cars[[2]][[2]]`.

In this case the first coordinate indicates make of the car, while the second indicates its colour.

I now wish to **swap the coordinates** so that the first coordinate would indicate colour, while the second would indicate the make of the car:

data on white BMW is in `cars[[1]][[1]]`, 
data on black BMW is in `cars[[2]][[1]]`, 
data on white GMC is in `cars[[1]][[2]]`, 
data on black GMC is in `cars[[2]][[2]]`.

Thus I want to **change the hierarchy** in a list of lists.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a super common task with lists. It sounds like it would be much better if you stored your data in a flat manner and just subset it as necessary. Nevertheless, here's one way you could swap. With the sample input

```
cars <- list(list("white BMW", "black BMW"), list("white GMC", "black GMC"))
```

you can do

```
i <- 1:length(cars)
j <- 1:length(cars[[1]])
swap<-lapply(j, function(j) lapply(i, function(i) cars[[i]][[j]]))
```

compare

```
cars[[2]][[1]]
# [1] "white GMC"
swap[[2]][[1]]
# [1] "black BMW"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution on the same sample data

`cars <- list(list("white BMW", "black BMW"), list("white GMC", "black GMC"))`

is

```
do.call(function(...) Map(list, ...), cars)
```

which keeps the names of the elements intact.